# After UNB, where do I go?

Tags: unity, upgrade, 10.04, ubuntu-netbook

I've been running Lucid NBR since forever and I love it. A recent kernel update broke some services and while a revision fixed them, the writing is on the wall, I have to update.

Unity fits on my netbook like an elephant in a bucket, but I read on a Linux Mint forum that I can modify the buttons on the Unity launcher to make them bigger, in some way emulating the UNB launcher.

Can someone tell me how I can do this?

The next step, of course is to get the launcher to show more launchers as its children. So, for example, I would have an electronics entry in the Unity launcher, and it would offer my electronics calculator, my circuit simulator, my schematics capture software and links to my parts suppliers and PCB manufacturers as a launcher. Similarly fo my programming stuff and my other applications. Is this possible? If so, can someone tell me how (in detail)?

Pogo (standing at the door and looking towards Linux Mint)

Answer (score 1):

The Appearances settings has a slider for the launcher icon size - <strike>and it can go pretty high, I think</strike>. My bad - it doesn't go very high (only about 25% more than the default):
[image: Appearances screenshot]

As for the second part, as I understand it, you want one launcher icon to do multiple things or you want multiple launcher icons added by you? For the former, you might have to create a custom desktop file and add actions to it. There is a detailed guide available at the [Ubuntu help centre](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Adding_shortcuts_to_a_launcher).

Essentially, it boils down to having multiple actions in the desktop file, with each action having its own `Exec` field, where you can put whatever command you want. For the latter, you just have to drop a desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/` - this is also mentioned in the help centre article linked above. I'm not adding a detailed guide here, since it would essentially involve me doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. :)
Here's a [sample file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7796643/) I tried out (in GNOME Shell, but it should work in Unity as well).

Finally, nothing prevents you from installing Cinnamon on Ubuntu. No need to go as far as Mint.